# Django: Elif syntax for rendering

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I have a template that allows me to toggle back and forth between a Customer Search and Event Search (results are displayed on a map).

However, I cannot seem to get them both working together!

```
class MapView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "index.html"

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if request.POST['customer_search']:
            self.object = CustomerAccount.objects.search(request.POST['customer_search'])
            return HttpResponse(serialize('geojson',self.object), content_type="application/json")
        elif request.POST['event_search']:
            self.object = Event.objects.search(request.POST['event_search'])
            return HttpResponse(serialize('geojson',self.object), content_type="application/json")
        else:
            raise SuspiciousOperation("Blank Request Received")
```

In this case the browser console returns the following error when i try to execute an 'event search':

```
500: MultiValueDictKeyError at /discover/
"'customer_search'"
```

If I reverse these (put the event on the if, and customer on the elif), then I get the opposite when I try to run a 'customer search':

```
500: MultiValueDictKeyError at /discover/
"'event_search'"
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: is 'search' your custom manager here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
request.POST.get('event_search', False)
request.POST.get('customer_search', False)
```

instead of :

```
request.POST['customer_search']
request.POST['event_search']
```

in the both case.

Comment: That worked beautifully! I didn't realize it needed a tuple. Thank you.